# Get reclassified area categories in hectares using Python and GDAL?

Tags: raster, gdal

I have a raster with reclassified values and I would like to get the area in hectares of those reclassified categories.

```
#RBR reclassification to USGS burn severity values

arr = np.array(RBR)

level1 = (arr >= -0.500) & (arr <= -0.251) #-2 #Enhanced Regrowth, high (post-fire)
level2 = (arr >= -0.250) & (arr <= -0.101) #-1 #Enhanced Regrowth, low (post-fire)
level3 = (arr >= -0.100) & (arr <= 0.99) #0 #Unburned
level4 = (arr >= 0.100) & (arr <= 0.269) #1 #Low Severity
level5 = (arr >= 0.270) & (arr <= 0.439) #2 #Moderate-low Severity
level6 = (arr >= 0.440) & (arr <= 0.659) #3 #Moderate-high Severity
level7 = (arr >= 0.660) & (arr <= 1.300) #4 #High Severity

levels = [level2, level3, level4, level5, level6, level7]
reclass_values = [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

RBR_reclassed_arr = np.where(level1,-2, arr)
for level, val in zip(levels, reclass_values):
RBR_reclassed_arr = np.where(level, val, RBR_reclassed_arr)

saveRaster(RBR_reclassed_arr,path_RBR_reclass,cols,rows,projection)
```

After this I plot a `cmap`, but this is not relevant in this case. So next I would like to get that areas in hectares:

```
levels = {
'Unburned': 0,
'Low Severity': 1,
'Moderate-low Severity': 2,
'Moderate-high Severity': 3,
'High Severity': 4
 }

for cat, val in levels.items():
n_pixels = (RBR_reclassed_arr == val).sum()
print(n_pixels)
```

[image]

After this I would like to get in ha:

```
gt = B8_prefire.GetGeoTransform()
pixel_area = gt[1] * abs(gt[5])
print(n_pixels)
```

[image]

Comment: 1 ha = 10000 m2. So, Pixels number×pixel area/10000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on @xunilk comment, yes, you would get the area of each category by multypling the number of pixels of the category by the pixel area / 10.000. Howver, keep in mind that this will work only if the spatial reference unit of your raster is meter. Otherwise, if it is for a example a degree, this won't yield accurate results.

Also, you should't access `n_pixels` outside the `for` loop as it will only give you the number of pixels of the last category (*i.e* 0). You have to compute the area inside the `for` loop. Your code could look something like this:

```py
gt = B8_prefire.GetGeoTransform()
pixel_area = gt[1] * abs(gt[5])

levels = {
'Unburned': 0,
'Low Severity': 1,
'Moderate-low Severity': 2,
'Moderate-high Severity': 3,
'High Severity': 4
 }

for cat, val in levels.items():
    n_pixels = (RBR_reclassed_arr == val).sum()
    area_ha = n_pixels * (pixel_area / 10000)
    print(f'Area for {cat}: {area_ha} ha.')
```

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers. I knew how to convert meters to hectares but I couldn't show the results with `print`. My raster's space unit is meters so it worked.

Comment: I'm glad it worked. If this answer solved your question please accept it so your question does not appear unanswered.